# Help adjusting height of unordered list and <h3> tag in html

Tags: html, html-lists

OK, I'm having this very very simple error, but I can't figure it out and it's been bugging me.

Taking a look at my page here:  http://www.marioplanet.com/product.htm

And looking at the unordered list after my header 3 tag reading "Features" you can tell there are some line breaks between the header 3 and the unordered list.

I added those there because I like having the header 3 tag aligned with the top of the images, but it looks funky without the bullets directly underneath the header 3, like they would be if there were no line breaks.

I am just wondering how to slide those bullets up! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td width="552" style="vertical-align: top;">
```